# How to filter out in SQL the records in a partionned ordered table where first records of group are null?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, sql-order-by, partition, row-number

### The Data

```
    ROW  YEAR  PROD   KEY   DATE
    1    2011  APPLE  TIME  2011-11-18 00:00:00.000
    2    2011  APPLE  TIME  2011-11-19 00:00:00.000
    3    2013  APPLE  NULL  2011-11-18 00:00:00.000
    4    2013  APPLE  NULL  2011-11-19 00:00:00.000
    5    2013  APPLE  TIME  2014-04-08 00:00:00.000
    6    2013  APPLE  DIM   2014-04-09 00:00:00.000
    7    2013  APPLE  TIME  2014-11-10 10:50:14.113
    8    2013  APPLE  TIME  2014-11-12 10:46:04.947
    9    2013  MELON  JAK   2011-10-17 11:01:19.657
    10   2013  MELON  TIME  2014-11-18 11:19:35.547
    11   2013  MELON  NULL  2014-11-19 11:19:35.547
    12   2013  MELON  TIME  2014-11-21 10:32:36.017
    13   2014  APPLE  JAK   2003-04-10 00:00:00.000
    14   2014  APPLE  DIM   2003-04-11 00:00:00.000
    15   2015  APPLE  TIME  2002-09-27 00:00:00.000
    16   2015  APPLE  NULL  2004-09-28 00:00:00.000
```

ROW is not a column in the table. Is just to show which records i want.

### The question

The above data is partitionned by (YEAR, PROD) and ordered by DATE.

I need to keep all the rows except row 3 and 4 based on the following logic :

- if the first rows of a group (here (YEAR, PROD)) are NULL, discard them.
- 11 and 16 are null but we keep them because they are not first of their group.

**Each group has to start with records that have a KEY that is are not null**

==> otherwise discard

In other words, i can have : not null, null, not null, null

But i cannot have : null, not null, null, not null

### Expected result

```
    ROW  YEAR  PROD   KEY   DATE
    1    2011  APPLE  TIME  2011-11-18 00:00:00.000
    2    2011  APPLE  TIME  2011-11-19 00:00:00.000

    5    2013  APPLE  TIME  2014-04-08 00:00:00.000
    6    2013  APPLE  DIM   2014-04-09 00:00:00.000
    7    2013  APPLE  TIME  2014-11-10 10:50:14.113
    8    2013  APPLE  TIME  2014-11-12 10:46:04.947
    9    2013  MELON  JAK   2011-10-17 11:01:19.657
    10   2013  MELON  TIME  2014-11-18 11:19:35.547
    11   2013  MELON  TIME  2014-11-19 11:19:35.547
    12   2013  MELON  TIME  2014-11-21 10:32:36.017
    13   2014  APPLE  JAK   2003-04-10 00:00:00.000
    14   2014  APPLE  DIM   2003-04-11 00:00:00.000
    15   2015  APPLE  TIME  2002-09-27 00:00:00.000
    16   2015  APPLE  TIME  2004-09-28 00:00:00.000
```

I want to do that, so later i have always a non null key at the begginning of each group.
In that way, i can later always use the former row to fill a subsequent records which have null value (in this example 11 and 16)

Any observation or suggestion would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gets the output you desire. I am checking of the value of key column between rows unbounded preceeding and current row, and since NULL has the  highest rank, if there are preceeding rows that are not null it would populate the field min_val with a NOT NULL column.

```
select * from (
select year,prod,key1,date1
       ,min(key1) over(partition by year,prod order by date1 asc) as min_val
  from t
   )x
where x.min_val is not null   


+------+-------+------+-------------------------+---------+
| year | prod  | key1 |          date1          | min_val |
+------+-------+------+-------------------------+---------+
| 2011 | APPLE | TIME | 2011-11-18 00:00:00.000 | TIME    |
| 2011 | APPLE | TIME | 2011-11-19 00:00:00.000 | TIME    |
| 2013 | APPLE | TIME | 2014-04-08 00:00:00.000 | TIME    |
| 2013 | APPLE | DIM  | 2014-04-09 00:00:00.000 | DIM     |
| 2013 | APPLE | TIME | 2014-11-10 10:50:14.113 | DIM     |
| 2013 | APPLE | TIME | 2014-11-12 10:46:04.947 | DIM     |
| 2013 | MELON | JAK  | 2011-10-17 11:01:19.657 | JAK     |
| 2013 | MELON | TIME | 2014-11-18 11:19:35.547 | JAK     |
| 2013 | MELON |      | 2014-11-19 11:19:35.547 | JAK     |
| 2013 | MELON | TIME | 2014-11-21 10:32:36.017 | JAK     |
| 2014 | APPLE | JAK  | 2003-04-10 00:00:00.000 | JAK     |
| 2014 | APPLE | DIM  | 2003-04-11 00:00:00.000 | DIM     |
| 2015 | APPLE | TIME | 2002-09-27 00:00:00.000 | TIME    |
| 2015 | APPLE |      | 2004-09-28 00:00:00.000 | TIME    |
+------+-------+------+-------------------------+---------+
```

link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae82f64802674aa60005b8e9f534a150

Answer (score 1):

There might be fancier solutions but in essence (you can remove the square brackets if KEY, DATE, etc are not reserved words in your product - I used TSQL):

```
select * 
from Tbl T1
where 
  /* Do not include if... */
  NOT (
       t1.[KEY] is null
       /* This is part of the first KEY=NULL rows for this group 
          (no preceding record with KEY<>NULL) */
        and not exists
           (select 1
            from Tbl T3
            where T3.[YEAR]=T1.[YEAR]
            and T3.PROD=T1.PROD
            and T3.[DATE] < T1.[DATE]
            and T3.[KEY] is not null
           )
       /* There are KEY<>NULL values further down */
       and exists 
           (select 1
            from Tbl T2
            where T2.[YEAR]=T1.[YEAR]
            and T2.PROD=T1.PROD
            and T2.[DATE] > T1.[DATE]
            and T2.[KEY] is not null
            )
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of query could help:

```
select YEAR, PROD, KEY, DATE
  from (
        select YEAR, PROD, KEY, DATE, 
               MIN(CASE WHEN KEY IS NULL THEN DATE ELSE NULL END)
               OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR, PROD) AS MIN_NULL_KEY_DATE,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR, PROD ORDER BY DATE ASC) RN
          from your_table yt
       )rpr
 where 1 = 1
   and CASE WHEN RN = 1 AND DATE = MIN_NULL_KEY_DATE THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = 1
```

so what did I try to achieve here: when the key column null we just found the min date based on year and prod columns. And also check that row is the first row of that group or not. If the rn = 1 and the date is equal min date value of when the key is null, then just ignore them in case when.